# Button and Button + CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

Hello I do have a question about the Android CheckBox =)

I do want to accomplish that if i press my reset button a TextView will clear its content.
This TextView also writes the content into a file.

If i tick my CheckBox and then press the Button the same thing happends but it should also delete the content from the file or just delete the file. -> to eliminate entries of older sessions which will be loaded otherwise.

```
//global
CheckBox mCheckFileDelete;

//setupWidgets() which is called by onCreate()
mCheckFileDelete = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cBdeleteFile);

//onClick (View view)
if (view.getId()==R.id.btn2reset && mCheckFileDelete.isChecked())
       {
           mMypoints.setText(null);
           mErgebnis.setText(null);
           setImage(5);
           mNotenHistory.setText("");
           //Delete File
           File f = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
           f.delete();


   }
else
{
mMypoints.setText(null);
mErgebnis.setText(null);
setImage(5);
mNotenHistory.setText("0");
}
```

Hope someone can give me hint. Is it really necessary to asign a seperate method to handle the whole isChecked() thing like the developer.android article shows?
Besides that i do not now how to implement this in my case.

Kind regards

//EDIT regarding a Question
MainActivity.onClick(View view)

```
Button berechne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1calc);
Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2reset);

    berechne.setOnClickListener(this);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       if (view.getId()==R.id.btn1calc)
       {
           //int ka_counter = 1;
           double mypoints = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(mMypoints.getText()));

           String spinner_maxpoints_string = mMaxPoints_spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
           double spinner_maxToDouble = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(spinner_maxpoints_string));

           double note = (6-(5*(mypoints/spinner_maxToDouble)));
           double note_rounded = Math.round(note*100)/100.0;
           String string_note = String.valueOf(note_rounded);
           mErgebnis.setText(string_note);


           if (string_note == null)
           {
                setImage(0);
           }
           else
           {
               if(note_rounded >= 1.0 && note_rounded <= 1.4)
               {
                   setImage(1);
               }
               else
               {
                   if (note_rounded >= 1.5 && note_rounded <= 1.9 )
                   {
                       setImage(2);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       if (note_rounded >= 2.0 && note_rounded <= 2.5)
                       {
                           setImage(3);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           if (note_rounded >= 2.6 && note_rounded <= 3.2)
                           {
                               setImage(4);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               if(note_rounded >= 3.3 && note_rounded <= 4.0)
                               {
                                   setImage(5);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   if(note_rounded >= 4.1 && note_rounded <= 4.9)
                                   {
                                       setImage(6);
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                       if(note_rounded >= 5.0 && note_rounded <= 6.0)
                                       {
                                           setImage(7);
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }

           }
           //ka_counter = ka_counter +1;

           //mNotenHistory.setText("KA " + ka_counter +": " + string_note + "\n" + mNotenHistory.getText().toString());
           mNotenHistory.setText(string_note + "\n" + mNotenHistory.getText().toString());
           try {
               FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
               fo.write(string_note.getBytes());
               fo.write("\n".getBytes());
               fo.close();

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }


       }

      if (view.getId()==R.id.btn2reset)
       {
           if(mCheckFileDelete.isChecked())
           {
                mMypoints.setText(null);
                mErgebnis.setText(null);
                setImage(0);
                mNotenHistory.setText("");
                //Delete File
                File f = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
                f.delete();
            }
           else
           {
               mMypoints.setText(null);
               mErgebnis.setText(null);
               setImage(0);
               mNotenHistory.setText("0");
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is/isn't working about your code? If by " Is it really necessary to asign a seperate method to handle the whole isChecked() ..." you mean the `checkChagedListener` then no. That is only needed if you want something to happen when the state of the `CheckBox` changes

Answer (score 0):

Within the onClick event check the status of the checkbox and then write your logic according to it. It should be something like this:

```
//onClick (View view)
if (view.getId()==R.id.btn2reset){
    if(mCheckFileDelete.isChecked()){
        mMypoints.setText(null);
        mErgebnis.setText(null);
        setImage(5);
        mNotenHistory.setText("");
        //Delete File
        File f = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
        f.delete();
    }
    else{
        mMypoints.setText(null);
        mErgebnis.setText(null);
        setImage(5);
        mNotenHistory.setText("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you just re-write the same code but split the `if` statement into two statements?

Comment: Exactly, in order to get the statuts of the checkbox within the onClick event.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I just don't see the difference in functionality.

Comment: @codeMagic there is a difference when the ID of the view is not btn2reset. on the original code the else block will fire, on the re-written code, the else block wont fire.

Comment: I rearranged the if statement. The app is not throwing an exception but is also not working. The file still exists if i check the checkBox and press the Button. But he does jump into the else statement because he will clear the TextView, set the image etc.

Comment: Sorry i have to correct me. It's nearly working. What he does is clear the TextViews and delete the file if the checkbox is checked and the reset button is pressed. But if i press my calculate button he will do th the else part oO and if i press reset he will do nothing.

Comment: How are you implementing the calculate button? You should use a different id and click event for each button. Can you please post the piece of code regarding to this?

Comment: First: The calculate thing worked fine bevore i implemented the rearranged if statment regarding reset/checkbox. Sorry Iam new to StackOverFlow do i have to post the code here in the comment or as answer on my Question? How do you want it?

Comment: oh ok, done but the problem is gone now. But i dont know why :D I just switched my case block where the image was set with this if block and now its working =/